# Is there a method in the Chirp SDK to inject a recorded, post-processed audio file?

Tags: chirp

Suppose I'm having trouble decoding a chirp sent from my phone (Chirp App from Google Play) to my laptop (SDK Running via Python). Let's say my microphone has a known, selective frequency response. Using the debug flag, I can write the recording out to an audio file.

In post-processing, I apply a digital filter to equalize my response. Now, I want to run this back through Chirp to test if I can decode the signal. For prototyping purposes, I would like to just run this back through Chirp as another wav file. Is there a "easy" way to do this?

If not, it looks like I can design my own audio-abstraction layer (chirpSDK.audioset). This seems useful if I write my filter to run in real-time on the audio stream. I have never done this. It seems possible but nontrivial. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `chirp-read` script to read an audio file. See https://developers.chirp.io/docs/tutorials/command-line

The source code for this is available here - https://github.com/chirp/chirp-python-examples/blob/master/audio/read.py

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.